# i want to make multiple mouseover functions with minimum codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 10 links and each of them is different from the others.I want when user hovers on them background image of the div changes and a tooltip text be shown on top of the links with a fade-in animation .

i have tried to make several functions using JS and it works but it's a lot of code and mostly repetitive.I want a good shortcut through all of that useless coding.

```js
document.getElementById("d1").onmouseover = function() {
  mouseOver1()
};
document.getElementById("d2").onmouseover = function() {
  mouseOver2()
};
document.getElementById("d3").onmouseover = function() {
  mouseOver3()
};
document.getElementById("d1").onmouseout = function() {
  mouseOut1()
};
document.getElementById("d2").onmouseout = function() {
  mouseOut2()
};
document.getElementById("d3").onmouseout = function() {
  mouseOut3()
};

function mouseOver1() {
  document.getElementById("dogs").style.background = "blue";
  document.getElementById("tooltiptext1").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function mouseOut1() {
  document.getElementById("dogs").style.background = "black";
  document.getElementById("tooltiptext1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function mouseOver2() {
  document.getElementById("dogs").style.background = "green";
  document.getElementById("tooltiptext2").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function mouseOut2() {
  document.getElementById("dogs").style.background = "black";
  document.getElementById("tooltiptext2").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function mouseOver3() {
  document.getElementById("dogs").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("tooltiptext3").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function mouseOut3() {
  document.getElementById("dogs").style.background = "black";
  document.getElementById("tooltiptext3").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
#dogs {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#d-list {
  color: white;
  direction: ltr;
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}

#tooltiptext1,
#tooltiptext2,
#tooltiptext3 {
  color: black;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="animals">
  <div id="dogs"></div>
  <div id="d-list">
    <pre style="font-size:22px; color:darkorange">dogs</pre><br />

    <pre><a href="#burger" id="d1">white Husky</a></pre>
    <p id="tooltiptext1">Tooltip text1</p>

    <pre><a href="#burger" id="d2">black Bull</a></pre>
    <p id="tooltiptext2">Tooltip text2</p>

    <pre><a href="#burger" id="d3">brown Rex</a></pre>
    <p id="tooltiptext3">Tooltip text3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please have in mind that all of links will change same outer div object and the idea is to change the background image of that div and the tooltip shoud appear on the top of the links....so,
any ideas?

Comment: I don't want to change their own backgrounds... I want to change another element's background and make a tooltip text be shown at the top of each link..           
like the user hovers on the "cute cat" link text and the background of a div changes to an img of the cat and a tooltip be shown that describes the cat.                          
and when the user hover on "cute dog" the background of the same div changes to an img of the dog and a tooltip be shown that describes the dog.

Comment: It is very unclear what "tooltip text be shown on top of them with a fade-in animation" references - and you did not appear to do anything to address that.  Please provide the HTML for everything here and how you tried to do what you mean by that.

Comment: is css out of the question?

Comment: I made an assumption that the missing `</div>` at the end was just a copy/paste issue and added it to your snippet

Comment: I am curious why you use all the `<prev></prev>` elements in there as it is a somewhat unusual set of element choice, was there a specific reason?

Comment: No i am simply an amator... i wanted to put a long space between color and race and i thought <pre> is a good tag for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: added animation requested.
CSS is almost always better done in script by using classes when multiple elements are being manipulated with similar functions so I used that here.  Rather than put some complex set of logic in place I simply added data attributes for the colors - now it works for any new elements you wish to add as well.

I did find your markup to be somewhat strangely chosen and would have done it differently but that was not part of the question as stated.

I took the liberty of removing the `style` attribute from your `dogs` element and put it in the CSS also as it seemed to belong there and mixing markup and css will probably make it harder to maintain over time and puts all the style in one place.

Since you DID tag this with jQuery here is an example of that.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#d-list').on('mouseenter', 'a', function(event) {
    $('#dogs').css('backgroundColor', $(this).data('colorin'));
    $(this).parent().next('.tooltip').animate({
      opacity: 1
    });
  }).on('mouseleave', 'a', function(event) {
    $('#dogs').css('backgroundColor', $(this).data('colorout'));
    $(this).parent().next('.tooltip').animate({
      opacity: 0
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#dogs {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#d-list {
  color: white;
  direction: ltr;
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}

.dog-header {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: darkorange;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.tooltip {
  color: black;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  position:relative;
  top:-4.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animals">
  <div id="dogs"></div>
  <div id="d-list">
    <pre class="dog-header">dogs</pre>
    <pre><a href="#burger" id="d1" data-colorin="blue" data-colorout="black">white Husky</a></pre>
    <p id="tooltiptext1" class="tooltip">Tooltip text1</p>
    <pre><a href="#burger" id="d2" data-colorin="green" data-colorout="black">black Bull</a></pre>
    <p id="tooltiptext2" class="tooltip">Tooltip text2</p>
    <pre><a href="#burger" id="d3" data-colorin="red" data-colorout="black">brown Rex</a></pre>
    <p id="tooltiptext3" class="tooltip">Tooltip text3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, the OP had some "curious" markup but this does what was asked - even if the OP has some non-standard markup and CSS there.

Comment: this does what i asked for...but can you put the tootlip on top of my text?

Comment: that should just be some CSS adjustment - do you want it to close up the space also?  As you have it now it keeps the space and simply manipulates the visibility attribute in the CSS so it still keeps the space

Comment: I added the css `position:relative;
  top:-4.5em;` to move it relative to it's original position.  I will leave the decision to keep the original space in the flow and the css to do that up to you.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

This answer was written before the question was edited to show the intended markup/styling and before all the details were included.  The code has been updated to work with that structure.

---

I think the simplest thing is just to create a configuration object to detail the varying bits, and then use common code for the rest.  Here's one approach:

```js
const configs = [
  ['d1', 'tooltiptext1', 'blue'], 
  ['d2', 'tooltiptext2', 'green'],
  ['d3', 'tooltiptext3', 'red'],
];

configs.forEach(([id, tt, color]) => {
  const dogs = document.getElementById('dogs');
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  const tip = document.getElementById(tt);
  el.onmouseover = (evt) => {
    dogs.style.background = color
    tip.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  el.onmouseout = (evt) => {
    dogs.style.background = "black";
    tip.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
})
```

```css
#dogs{float:right;margin-top:5%;background:#000;width:150px;height:150px}#d-list{color:#fff;direction:ltr;float:right;width:60%;height:60%}#tooltiptext1,#tooltiptext2,#tooltiptext3{color:#000;background-color:gray;width:120px;height:30px;border-radius:6px;text-align:center;padding-top:5px;visibility:hidden}
```

```html
<div id="animals"> <div id="dogs"></div><div id="d-list"> <pre style="font-size:22px; color:darkorange">dogs</pre><br/> <pre><a href="#burger" id="d1">white Husky</a></pre> <p id="tooltiptext1">Tooltip text1</p><pre><a href="#burger" id="d2">black Bull</a></pre> <p id="tooltiptext2">Tooltip text2</p><pre><a href="#burger" id="d3">brown Rex</a></pre> <p id="tooltiptext3">Tooltip text3</p></div></div>
```

Obviously you can extend this with new rows really easily.  And if you want to add more varying properties, you can simply make the rows longer.  If you need to add too many properties to each list, an array might become hard to read, and it might become better to switch to `{id: 'demo', tt: 'dem', color: 'blue'}` with the corresponding change to the parameters in the `forEach` callback.  (That is, replacing `configs.forEach(([id, tt, color]) => {` with `configs.forEach(({id, tt, color}) => {`.)  But with only three parameters, a short array seems cleaner.

---

### Older code snippet based on my made-up markup.

```js
const configs = [
  ['demo', 'dem', 'blue'], 
  ['dd', 'dem1', 'green']
];

configs.forEach(([id1, id2, color]) => {
  const a = document.getElementById(id1)
  const b = document.getElementById(id2)
  a.onmouseover = (evt) => {
    a.style.background = color
    b.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  a.onmouseout = (evt) => {
    a.style.background = "black";
    b.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
})
```

```css
div {width: 50px; height: 50px; float: left; margin: 10px; background: black; border: 1px solid #666; color: red; padding: 10px; text-align: center}
#dem , #dem1{visibility:hidden;}
```

```html
<div id="demo">demo</div>
<div id="dem">dem</div>
<div id="dd">dd</div>
<div id="dem1">dem1</div>
```

Comment: this is very good but i want that both of them to change another div's background.....both change the same div's background and show different tooltip texts

Comment: This does not address the tooltip and while a bit more common, changes the markup significantly.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: This answer was written before the question was edited to add any html or css.  Is the edit history correct that it was you that added all of that?  If so, I think it was an inappropriate edit, changing far too much from the the OPs question.

Comment: No, I merely formatted the poorly formatted code which is easily seen in the edit history.  Not a surprise that given it is a new contributor to the site.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Sorry, for whatever reason, I'm not seeing the edit history correctly on my mobile.  In any case, this answer was based off the original question, not the edited version.  I think the ideas of it carry over without much change.

Comment: Updated to capture more detailed requirements.

Answer (score 0):

my way of seeing that => zero Javascript:

```css
div[data-info] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:80px 20px 0 0;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
div[data-bg=blue]:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
div[data-bg=green]:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
}
div[data-info]:hover:after {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 46px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-info);
  left: 20%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 220px;
}
div[data-info]:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0px 6px;
  bottom: 40px;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div data-info="Tooltip for A Tooltip for A" data-bg="blue">with Tooltip CSS3 A</div>
<div data-info="Tooltip for B" data-bg="green" >with Tooltip CSS3 B</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help...but i want them to change another div's background and show different tooltip texts....both change the same div's background and show different tooltip texts on top of them

Comment: `@salar abbasi`... well, I changed this.

Comment: This while a bit more common, changes the markup significantly and the appearance of the result totally differs from that in the OP's example.

Comment: Do not make me believe that changing colors in css is an intellectual crime